# Can I run a script on my Pi and keep it running when I close SSH?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running Debian Lite (terminal only, no desktop). I've installed Node.js and am currently running a script by making an SSH connection through puTTY.

The problem is, when I close the puTTY window the script stops running. I need it to run when my desktop is turned off, otherwise having it on the Pi is pointless.

So far I have tried:
-Nohup | Appended the output but still stopped running when I closed the terminal.

Comment: having a Pi is never pointless. Could you post your script here? We might come up with a way to do a For loop and never stop etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple options:

Install `screen` or `tmux` on the PI and start the job with those programs.

(or) Run the job with the `nohup` command:

```
nohup command
```

(or) Run the job in the background and use `disown`:

```
command &
disown %1
```

I recommend option 1.

Comment: Would I need desktop access for screen or tmux or can I install and run through terminal?

Comment: You can run it from terminal

Comment: I wasn't doing the nohup command properly. Added a & after the command and it works perfectly.